# What's the way to check others servers IIS status from asp.net page?

Tags: asp.net, sql, iis

I need to check every five minutes if 4 servers are online from one asp.net page running in a fifth server, in order to redirect requests and send alert by e-mail to the network manager. Specifically I need to know if IIS is running ok in those servers. What's the best way to do it? Is there any component or socket library to use in order to accomplish the task?
Any example code?

The same problem with other two SQL servers from wich I need to know if the SQL service is up.

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: This would be good for serverfault.com, where they probably know the tools.

Comment: I'm not searching for a specific tool, I need to resolve this programatically!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know if IIS is running, why don't you just send an HTTP GET to a resource on each server.  If you get a successful response, then the server is up.  Same idea with SQL - if you know a login and table name, just do a query.